# Django how to order queryset based on filtered many to many field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

Hi all i'm trying to figure out how to order a queryset based on a manyToMany field but I need to filter that field as well. Here is the exact problem.

```
qs = Drink.objects.all()
```

I want to order this queryset by a related field `ingredientsuserneeds`

Models:

```
class IngredientsUserNeeds(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    drinks = models.ManyToManyField(Drink)
    count_need = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Drink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
```

In a DRF list view, I want to order the queryset by the drink's `ingredientuserneeds_set` but filtered by the user which will return a queryset that is of length one, finally ordering by that single object's count_need in the queryset. It would be sorta like

```
qs = qs.order_by('ingredientsuserneeds_set__filter(user=user)__first()__count_need')
```

But clearly, you cant do what i typed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Case, When, F

Drink.objects.all().annotate(
    count_need=Case(When(
        ingredients__user__email='wanaryytel@outlook.com', then=F('ingredients__count_need')), 
        output_field=models.IntegerField()
    )
).first().count_need
```